# unable to connect to windows netcat listener

Tags: windows, firewall, netcat, nmap

I set a netcat listener on my windows 7 machine

`nc -nvlp 4444`

Then I try to connect to it via kali linux:

`nc -nv <Target_Ip_address> 4444`

I get a connection refused. However, if I connect locally from the windows machine to the port I get a successul connection.  In addition, when I run an `nmap` scan on the port I get its filtered.  However, I never messed with any firewall and there are other ports that are open. The only problem is I can not open any ports to connect to (including port 4444) besides the ones already opened. Any help would be appreciated

I have tried to open other ports besides 4444 but none work.  I attempted to connect to the ports already open and those worked.

I run `nc -zvw3 <Target_IPAddress> 4444` on kali linux and get connection timed out.  I verify the port is open on windows machine by `netstat -a`.  I don't understand why I can't connect

Comment: Does your firewall allow that(ingoing, port 4444)? Is the port open(`netstat -an`)?

Comment: The port is open on the windows machine.  I ran netstat -an in order to verify that it is open.  Thank you.  It was definitely the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Some ports will be open in windows by default. What you're looking for is the advanced firewall settings.

You can find this by pressing `WIN+R` and entering `wf.msc`. You can also find the advanced settings in  `Control Panel/System` and `security/Windows Firewall/Advanced settings`. Here, you can add new policies to your inbound and outbound rules for both programs and ports.

Per example, here is how you open up port 4444 for inbound traffic:

```
Go to "Inbound Rules"
Click on "New Rule..." in the actions list
Select "Port"
Choose whether you want to apply your rule to TCP or UDP traffic
Enter 4444 in the textbox
Choose "Allow the connection"
Check where the rule should apply
Give it a name.
```

Make sure to pay attention to what you do however as it is very possible to introduce security risks here.